# How to easily reconnect to hidden WIFI network - Windows 8

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, automation, internet-connection, wifi-configuration

If I turn off my laptop when it is not connected to the hidden WIFI I use, I have to manually select the "hidden network" item in the WIFI network list, then enter the SSID, and then enter the password - EVERY TIME.  How do I fix this?  I want to turn on my computer, hit a single button, and be connected to that network.  ---  I need to be able to regularly connect and disconnect with no issues and no hassles. ---  Also, what happened to the old "connect even if this network is not broadcasting it's SSID" menu item that was in previous versions of Windows?  I can't find any way to edit the properties of known (previously connected) Wifi networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following way to reconfigure to hidden wifi network.

To manually configure a wireless network with Windows 8, please follow these steps:

1. Open **Control Panel** from the menu.
2. Open the **Network and Internet**.
3. Open the **Network and Sharing Center**.
4. Click the **Set up a new connection or network**.
5. Select **Manually connect to a wireless network** from the list and click **Next**. The following dialog box as shown in the figure below will appear.

[image]

6. Enter the network name and select the appropriate settings according to our network requirements.
7. Click **Close** when we finish it.

For more details we can refer the link:
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-connect-hidden-wireless-networks-windows-8

Comment: I didn't think that would work, but it did - my comment about the "not broadcasting flag" was just a complaint.   Now I see the SSID listed, with no connection strength bars, so I can select it.  --  Why doesn't Windows let you edit an existing profile so you can edit the "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting" flag???

Comment: I'm jumping on a _really_ dead horse here but if you go to the 'Metro' control panel from your WiFi icon, there's a 'Manage known networks' link which brings one to a list of known/saved WiFi access points. This should include the network you've just configured but forgot to set the flag. Deleting it and restarting the manual connect/add/registration process (don't forget the flag/checkbox now :) ) _should_ work.